# copying files remotely over ssh does not work

Tags: server, ssh, rsync, scp

I tried to copy recursively a folder from my linux mashine to a remote one, but it did not work. I tried with both scp and rsync, but in both cases no files were copied, although I recieved a confirmation message. Here is my log:

```
aleks@ThinkPad-T530:/opt/homeToDeal/werbung/column$ scp -rp /opt/homeToDeal/werbung administrator@heimdi.at:/opt/homeToDeal/werbung
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'heimdi.at' differs from the key for the IP address '185.101.157.64'
Offending key for IP in /home/aleks/.ssh/known_hosts:2
Matching host key in /home/aleks/.ssh/known_hosts:5
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
administrator@heimdi.at's password: 
ue_hor.png                                    100%  639KB 110.7KB/s   00:05    
striche_hor.png                               100%  730KB 110.8KB/s   00:06    
striche_vert.png                              100%  346KB 119.7KB/s   00:02    
ue_vert.png                                   100%  435KB 119.0KB/s   00:03
```

But when I logg on to the remote mashine I get:

```
administrator@14980:/opt/homeToDeal/werbung/row$ ls
administrator@14980:/opt/homeToDeal/werbung/row$ cd ..
administrator@14980:/opt/homeToDeal/werbung$ cd column
administrator@14980:/opt/homeToDeal/werbung/column$ ls
administrator@14980:/opt/homeToDeal/werbung/column$
```

When I tried with rsync I got:

```
aleks@ThinkPad-T530:/opt/homeToDeal$ rsync -avz -e 'ssh' /opt/homeToDeal/werbung administrator@heimdi.at:/opt/homeToDeal/werbung
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'heimdi.at' differs from the key for the IP address '185.101.157.64'
Offending key for IP in /home/aleks/.ssh/known_hosts:2
Matching host key in /home/aleks/.ssh/known_hosts:5
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
administrator@heimdi.at's password: 
sending incremental file list
werbung/
werbung/column/
werbung/column/striche_vert.png
werbung/column/ue_vert.png
werbung/row/
werbung/row/striche_hor.png
werbung/row/ue_hor.png
```

but, again, no files were copied.

Comment: OK, thank you, but that is not my problem right now. I would appreciate helping me with copying the files.

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the correct directory in the remote server? Try running `pwd` after logging in. Also `ls -lR /opt/homeToDeal/werbung` might show your files.

Comment: Are you copying to the correct RemoteServer?

Comment: Yes, I have only one RemoteServer, so the IP and the domain  names are correctr

Comment: I suspect the files did copy, you just have to find them. Look in `/opt/homeToDeal/werbung/werbung`. Otherwise update the data base, `sudo updatedb`, and then `locate striche_hor.png`.

Comment: Try copying them to another place on the remote server: `scp -rp /opt/homeToDeal/werbung administrator@heimdi.at:/tmp/.`

Comment: @DougSmythies Thank you for your advice. Actually, that solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DougSmythies put it in his comment:

*"I suspect the files did copy, you just have to find them. Look in /opt/homeToDeal/werbung/werbung."*

Yes, this was actually the case. So, next time I copy recursively a folder, I should make sure that the destination folder DOES NOT include the very last source folder in the path, i.e.

instead of

```
  scp -rp /opt/homeToDeal/werbung administrator@heimdi.at:/opt/homeToDeal/werbung
```

I shall have

```
  scp -rp /opt/homeToDeal/werbung administrator@heimdi.at:/opt/homeToDeal/
```

or, respectively, instead of

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh' /opt/homeToDeal/werbung administrator@heimdi.at:/opt/homeToDeal/werbung
```

I shall have

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh' /opt/homeToDeal/werbung administrator@heimdi.at:/opt/homeToDeal
```